# How to get names of loaded or referenced assemblies in the current app domain for passing to a C# compiler?

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, codedom

I was using this:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().SelectMany<Assembly,string>( a => a.GetModules().Select<Module,string>( m => m.FullyQualifiedName )).ToArray()
```

to get the names of all loaded assemblies.

It comes from code that gets a friendly C# name for a type:

```
return (Type)(new CSharpCodeProvider().CompileAssemblyFromSource( new CompilerParameters( AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Select<Assembly,string>( a => a.CodeBase).ToArray(), null, false) {GenerateExecutable = false, GenerateInMemory = true, TreatWarningsAsErrors = false, CompilerOptions = "/optimize"}, "public static class C{public static System.Type M(){return typeof(" + friendlyName + ");}}").CompiledAssembly.GetExportedTypes()[0].GetMethod("M").Invoke( null, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static, null, null, null ));
```

But the compiler is producing an error like so:
Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\qk3bjlf3.dll' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Problem is... that file is not actually referenced anywhere.  It's not returned by AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() nor any of the submodules, and the name changes every time I click continue in the debugger.

Comment: That's a dynamically-generated assembly. It may only be in memory.

Comment: `GenerateInMemory = true`

Answer (score 0):

Actually i do like this:

```
var assemblies = new List<string>();
assemblies.AddRange(new List<string>(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
  .Where((a) => !a.IsDynamic).Select((a) => a.CodeBase
  .Replace("file:\\", "")
  .Replace("file:///", ""))));
```

Just in case (since i use this a lot) i created a small library to accomply this kind of things

The code and documentation are here: [Kendar Expression Builder](http://kendar.org/?p=/dotnet/sharptemplate)
While the nuget package is here: [Nuget Sharp Template](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpTemplate/)